# Упростить выражение, чтобы было меньше символов

Tags: c++

```
x[i] + x[i + 1] + x[i + 2] > m ? m = x[i] + x[i + 1] + x[i + 2] : 0;
```

Как можно упростить, чтобы было меньше символов?

Comment: Вы точно понимаете, как тернарный оператор работает?

Comment: @gbg да, суть не в смысле кода, а в уменьшении количества символов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, вы ищите это:

```
#define M(a, b) (a)>(b) ? (a) : (b)
m = M(x[i] + x[i+1] + x[i+2], m);
```

Comment: я бы хотел увидеть что-то подобное m = x[i] + x[i + 1] + x[i + 2] > m; приоритет ">" выше (если бы это было возможно)

Comment: для функций нужно дополнительно подключать #include <numeric> и приписывать std:: (х2) это добавляет больше символов, но идея хорошая

Comment: @gbg, вот теперь (с define), это уже совсем другое дело

Comment: @gbg не подскажете ?https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1316566/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-abort-called-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5?noredirect=1#comment2324342_1316566  (тест в комментариях)

Answer (score 4):

```
y = x[i] + x[i + 1] + x[i + 2];
y > m ? m = y : 0;
```

Comment: я бы хотел увидеть что-то подобное m = x[i] + x[i + 1] + x[i + 2] > m; приоритет ">" выше (если бы это было возможно)

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что речь идёт о кол-ве символов. Тогда лучше всего сделать так:

```
m = max(x[i] + x[i + 1] + x[i + 2], m)
```

Это самый короткий вариант.